# Get extending description fromn dlerror()

Tags: c++, dll, dlopen

I'm trying to work with the Anjuta on Linux.

I created a project which has some .a and .so libraries, then compiled it. The compilation went successfully.

Since dlopen() can load the .so libraries only when they are installed I ran "make install". The installation went successful.

Then I tried to run the program inside Anjuta. However I received an error that one of the libraries can not be found. That message came from the dlerror() call.

Just to make sure I did "ls -la" on "/usr/local/lib" and the library is there. However I suspect that there is a dependency on some other .so library that is missing.

So my questions are:

1. Is my suspicion correct?
2. If it is - would it be more appropriate to give more meaningful message? (This is actually a rhetorical question)
3. Is there a way to find what library dependency I'm missing if the 1 is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my suspicion correct?

Possibly.

> If it is - would it be more appropriate to give more meaningful message? (This is actually a rhetorical question)

No, it would not be appropriate to give you any message you didn't ask for. It is *your* job to obtain such message by calling `dlerror`.

> Is there a way to find what library dependency I'm missing if the 1 is correct?

Yes: examine the result of calling `dlerror` when `dlopen` fails.

On Linux, setting `LD_DEBUG=libs` in the environment may also provide clues.